# How to change Android WebView cache directory path? So I can save different caches folder for each WebView in my app?

Tags: android, caching, webview

Right now I have this:

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    private void createWebViewer(WebView webView, FrameLayout frameLayout, String profile) {

        webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        });

        frameLayout.addView(webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/profiles/" + profile);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("WebView Client");

        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

But even tho I'm setting: webSettings.setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/profiles/" + profile); the cache still goes to the default cache location.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?